# Performing one-way Welch's ANOVA using summary statistics

Tags: r

I want to test for a difference between four independent groups. I have three unequal samples with raw data, and one sample for which I have summary statistics only. I want to compare all of these using one-way ANOVA, but to allow for heteroscedacity I need to use Welch's ANOVA. I would also like to perform a post-hoc test (Games-Howell). I understand there is the `ind.oneway.second` in the R package `rpsychi` but it doesn't seem like this has an option for Welch's correction.

```
means <- c(30.335,71.998,121.030,150.071)
sd <- c(19.335,26.147,14.988,37.974)
n <- c(15,37,6,6)
```

Please let me know if any other information would be useful. Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What's your question?

Comment: There exists an excellent post on CrossValidated that is probably relevant: [How to perform two-sample t-tests in R by inputting sample statistics rather than the raw data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/how-to-perform-two-sample-t-tests-in-r-by-inputting-sample-statistics-rather-tha)

Comment: Are you suggesting performing multiple Welch's t-tests and correcting the p-values for type I errors? Yes that could work